# Setting up and using DreamWeaver and IIS/ASP with FTP

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver, iis-7

I have a copy of DreamWeaver CS5 and have installed Microsoft IIS 7.  How do I set up DreamWeaver to use IIS server as my test server with ASP and FTP?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install FileZilla server (which is a free FTP server) and create an FTP user who has access to your DocumentRoot (or whatever Microsoft calls it).  The good news is that FileZilla is free, open source software, and that it complies with official internet standards (so it will work perfectly with DreamWeaver which is known to depend on these well-known and officially recognized standards).

FileZilla Server
  http://www.filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

Once you have that configured, you'll need to configure DreamWeaver to use that FTP account, and connect to the FTP server hosted at 127.0.0.1 (localhost -- the IP address of your local computer that never changes, which every computer with standard TCP/IP has).